# Why does "ip link add" not work in rc.local?

Tags: networking, startup, interface

I used the following command to add a dummy interface:

```
sudo ip link add name mydummy type dummy
```

It works great. But when I put this in `rc.local` before the `exit 0` command, it does not work. After login to the system, `ifconfig` does not show the `mydummy` interface.

Comment: use `ifconfig` with `-a` switch to see down interfaces too.

Comment: no difference. ifconfig -a shows the same result.

Comment: what error is shown in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Are `rc.local` sysntax is ok? Does `sudo bash /etc/rc.local`  add your desired interface?

Comment: the syntax is ok. sudo bash /etc/rc.local is done successfully.

Comment: Sudo is not possible in rc.local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a dummy interface needs a dummy kernel module that is not loaded when `rc.local` is executed. There are many methods to run a program at boot time, but the best way is using a service file.

I suppose that your Ubuntu box supports `upstart` technology. I name this service `dummyadder`.

1. Create the file `/etc/init/dummyadder.conf` and add the following lines:

   ```
   start on runlevel [2345]

   script
   ip link add name mydummy type dummy
   ip link set dev mydummy up
   end script

   pre-stop exec ip link del mydummy
   ```
2. Reboot your Linux to see the result.

Comment: `ip link` create the interface at down state. `ip link set dev mydummy up` to bring it up.